# How do I get a lightning card to expand to the size of the enclosing layout item?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-card, lightning-tabset

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout size="12"
                        multiple-rows="true"
                        vertical-align="stretch"
                        class="container-layout">
        <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto"
                                padding="around-small"
                                class="top-row"
                                size="7">
            <lightning-card title="Prospects">
                1
            </lightning-card>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto"
                                padding="around-small"
                                class="top-row"
                                size="5">
            <lightning-card title="Prospect Detail">
                2
            </lightning-card>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto"
                                padding="around-small"
                                class="bottom-row"
                                size="7">
            <lightning-card>
                <lightning-tabset>
                    <lightning-tab label="To Do">
                        tasks
                    </lightning-tab>
                    <lightning-tab label="My Schedule">
                        schedule
                    </lightning-tab>
                    <lightning-tab label="My Stats">
                        stats
                    </lightning-tab>
                </lightning-tabset>
            </lightning-card>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto"
                                padding="around-small"
                                class="bottom-row"
                                size="5">
            <lightning-card>
                <lightning-tabset>
                    <lightning-tab label="Chatter">
                        chatter
                    </lightning-tab>
                    <lightning-tab label="Activity">
                        activity
                    </lightning-tab>
                </lightning-tabset>
            </lightning-card>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

Here's the current CSS:

```
.large {
    height: 200px;
}

.container-layout {
    height: 80vh;
}

.custom-box {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f4f6f9;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid #d8dde6;
}

.top-row {
    height: 70%;
}

.bottom-row {
    height: 30%;
}

lightning-card {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

It produces the following rendered page:

[image: screenshot]

What I'd like is for the tab groups and lightning cards to take the full vertical size of the enclosing layout items. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using vanilla CSS grids.

```html
<template>
    <div class="major-grid">
        <div class="top-left slds-theme_default">
            <div class="top-left-header">
                <h1>Prospects</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <c-new-opps-header></c-new-opps-header>
            </div>
            <div>
                <c-new-opps-datatable></c-new-opps-datatable>
            </div>
            <div>
                <c-new-opps-header></c-new-opps-header>
            </div>
            <div>
                <c-new-opps-datatable></c-new-opps-datatable>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="top-right slds-theme_default">

        </div>
        <div class="bottom-left slds-theme_default">

        </div>
        <div class="bottom-right slds-theme_default">

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```css
h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.major-grid {
    display: grid;
    height: 80vh;
    margin-right: 10px;
    grid-template-rows: 70% 30%;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.top-left {
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 4% 10% 39% 49%;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lightning-grid` here.

I created this sample component for what you need and you can insert `lightning-card` in each grid like I have done for 1st and 2nd column.

https://webcomponents.dev/edit/XdVtgPF8S9or38o0F3vk

Try this...

https://webcomponents.dev/edit/XdVtgPF8S9or38o0F3vk/src/app.html

Comment: @Chuck did it work for you? Do you need more help?

Comment: I checked the link above last night and saw the code you offered, but when I tried to load the page again, the code was gone, so I wasn't able to try it out.

Comment: @Chuck Link works for me still so it should work for you, can you check app.html?

Comment: I updated link try and see that one.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. I have four layout items in a 12x12 grid, and they're spaced how I want them, but the components within each of the four sections only expand as needed for their contents. I want them to expand to their maximum height, with the same spacing between the columns as I have between the rows.

Comment: For spacing between the column you can use ‘padding’ that gives you option to add padding any side of the card or component you want. You can also add the minimum size for each of these cards and that will expand the layout items to where you wantz